# Meteor.call issue in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to know about the usage of `Meteor.call`. I did a simple example as shown below. The problem is that it never goes to `insertDetails()`. Can you please check the below code and suggest me what to do so that I don't get the **Match Failed** error.

Client.JS

```
Meteor.methods
({
    //this method doesn't cal when using meteor.cal
    insertDetails : function(adData, callback)
     {
       console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ******* insertDetails ");
        checkFields(adData);
        var fields = 
        {
            userID: adData.UserID,
            fname: adData.fname,
            lname: adData.lname,
            dob: adData.dob
         };

         return Client.insert(fields, callback);
      }
});


// SERVER-SIDE HELPERS ************************************

var nonEmpty = Match.Where(function(x) {return !!x;});

var checkFields = function(adData)
 {
   console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> checkFields ");
   check(adData.userID, nonEmpty);
    check(adData.fname, nonEmpty);

};
```

Insert.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) 
{
  Template.hello.events({
    'submit #addnewuserdetails': function (e,t)

     {

      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')

      console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Add button in details ");

      e.preventDefault();
          saveClientDetails();
    }
  });
}


var saveClientDetails = function() 
{
    console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> saveClientDetails ");
   var fields =  {
        //ownerId: Meteor.userId(),
                        UserID : $('#userid').value

                    ,fname : $('#fname').value

            ,lname :$('#lname').value

            ,dob : $('#dob').value


    };
      console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> fields.UserID "+fields.UserID);    
        //here cal to above insertDetails()
         Meteor.call("insertDetails", fields, function(err, result)
           {
              if (!err)
                  {
                       console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> saveClientDetails Success");
                   } 
               else 
                {
                      console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> saveClientDetails ERROR "+err.reason);
                 }
        });

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Match Failed` error points to invalid data being rejected by your check function. My guess is that the problem is with user id: when you call the method you use `UserID` parameter, but then you check lowercase `userID`. Try fixing that and see whether it works. Also, try commenting out `check` call and see whether the rest of code is running. Also, how do you verify that the method was not called? Notice that log should be visible in the server console.

Comment: No That is not a problem and also i checked once.The Meteor.call never goes to that method.Can you please suggest me.@Hubert OG